# Web Api 2 Iterator block exception not caught by IExceptionLogger service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller returning an `IEnumerable<T>` and I'm using `yield return` to generate the list. When an exception is thrown in the iterator block, the exception is returned in the response, however the IExceptionLogger service I've added isn't catching the exception. It is catching, it seems all other exceptions. Any ideas?

I've setup my logger service in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services


        config.Services.Add(typeof(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionLogger), new T5ExceptionLogger());
```

I've created this sample controller to demonstrate my issue.

```
public class TestingController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<string> Get() //Method not being caught
    {
        string s = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            yield return s.ToString(); //This will throw a Null Reference exception (NOT caught)
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Post()
    {
        throw new Exception("Test"); //This IS caught
    }

}
```

Edit: Just to add that it seems to be to do with lazy iteration and I can force enumeration with a `ToList()` call but I just wanted to find out if it is just a limitation of the IExceptionLogger service and WebApi that it cannot catch exceptions in this case.

Comment: Can you try [registering the logger before initializing WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938542/asp-net-webapi-iexceptionlogger-doesnt-catch-exceptions)?

Comment: I moved the service registration and nothing has changed. Just to reiterate, the ExceptionLogger seems to work for all cases except the scenario above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be due to lazy iteration?

If the lifetime of the logging service matches the controller, but the iteration is happening after the controller has been disposed, then there is no error handler any more when the iteration throws.

Try moving the iterator into a helper method and forcing it to iterate in the controller with `ToList()`.

Comment: Yes, the stack trace does suggest lazy iteration and forcing enumeration within the action with `ToList()`does fix things. I am just trying to understand WHY this example doesn't work. I thought the ExceptionLogger service would exist be beyond lifetime of the controller.

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer. I'm just holding out to see if anyone can explain why it won't catch exceptions in lazy iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the exception is not caught is that Web Api's exception filters cannot catch

> Exceptions thrown during response content serialization

See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling